# How to ignore a null/space character in?

Tags: c++

My output is slightly off. Right now my output looks like this:

```
 Is this correct??
 My Project works!!!!
 *************** I don't know
```

I need it to look like this:

```
Is this correct???
My Project works!!!!!
****************I don't know
```

The null character/space is messing up all 3 lines for me and I'm uncertain of how to ignore a null in this instance.

My input file looks like this:

```
63-27.8 18spaces L Is this correct
33fill 21b5 l My Project works
42??? 28-09ng5 R I don't know
```

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filename;
    int a, b, c; // ASCII values for fill character
    int aw, bw, cw; // width values for setwidth
    char ch1, ch2, ch3; // character for right or left justification
    string s1, s2, s3; // strings

    ifstream inData;

    cout << "please enter the location of the file you wish to input: " << endl;
    getline(cin, filename);

    inData.open(filename.c_str());


    inData >> a;
    inData.ignore(100, ' ');
    inData >> aw;
    inData.ignore(100, ' ');
    inData >> ch1;
    getline(inData, s1);
    inData >> b;
    inData.ignore(100, ' ');
    inData >> bw;
    inData.ignore(100, ' ');
    inData >> ch2;
    getline(inData, s2);
    inData >> c;
    inData.ignore(100, ' ');
    inData >> cw;
    inData.ignore(100, ' ');
    inData >> ch3;
    getline(inData, s3);
    {
        if  (ch1 == 'l' || ch1 == 'L')
            cout << left;
        else if (ch1 == 'r' || ch1 == 'R')
            cout << right;
        else
            cout << "error" << endl;
    }
    cout << setw(aw) << setfill(char(a)) << s1 << endl;
    {
        if  (ch2 == 'l' || ch2 == 'L')
            cout << left;
        else if (ch2 == 'r' || ch2 == 'R')
            cout << right;
        else
            cout << "error" << endl;
    }
    cout << setw(bw) << setfill(char(b)) << s2 << endl;
    {
        if  (ch3 == 'l' || ch3 == 'L')
            cout << left;
        else if (ch3 == 'r' || ch3 == 'R')
            cout << right;
        else
            cout << "error" << endl;
    }
    cout << setw(cw) << setfill(char(c)) << s3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

how would you correct this problem?

Comment: Smells like a homework assignment.

Comment: "Smells like a homework assignment", Tom Huffed

Comment: It is but I'm very stuck at the moment and can't visit the computer lab for assistance because my father in-law borrowed my vehicle today

Comment: @gleng So what? It’s a valid question. OP isn’t asking us do to their homework, merely to help out in a tight spot.

Comment: I have tried adding inData.ignore(' '); and inData.ignore('\0'); after the ch1, ch2, ch3 inputs but neither works

Comment: never mind I got it. I didn't realize that you need an integer before you can ignore a space. I added inData.ignore(100, ' '); after the ch1, ch2, ch3 inputs and that corrected the problem. After a few hours of searching it was a lucky guess that fixed it for me -.-